# why is my list object add function not working?

Tags: c#

I can't seem to add a Character class in to my List object:

```
public class Character
{
    public string  OP_Name { get; set; }
    public int     Star_Rarity { get; set; }

    public Character(string name, int star)
    {
        OP_Name = name;
        Star_Rarity = star;
    }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    List<Character> guard = new List<Character>();
    guard.Add(new Character() {Op_Name = "Abc", Star_Rarity = 5});
}
```

I also have a follow up question:

Is there a way to generate a List faster on initialization instead of having to add the object in to the list?

I made a constructor but don't know how to get it to work.

Please and thank you for the help!

Comment: What does the error message tell you?

Comment: When you read the document [Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) for c#, what part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no default constructor, so you have to pass the arguments the constructor is expecting:

```
guard.Add(new Character("Abc", 5));
```

If you added a default constructor, you'd have the option to keep it the way you currently do or to do it the way I just showed:

```
public Character() { }  // default constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second half of your question: *"Is there a way to generate a List faster on initialization instead of having to add the object in to the list?"*.  The answer is "sort of".  You can use Collection Initialization syntax (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers).  However, if you read that description, you'll see that that results in your list constructor being called and then `Add` being called repeatedly.

So, it's not any faster, but it is easier to type and and to read.  Taking your intial code and modifying it...

```
public class Character
{
    public string  OP_Name { get; set; }
    public int     Star_Rarity { get; set; }

    public Character() { }

    public Character(string name, int star)
    {
        OP_Name = name;
        Star_Rarity = star;
    }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    List<Character> guard = new List<Character>
    {
        new Character() {Op_Name = "Abc", Star_Rarity = 5},
        new Character() {Op_Name = "Def", Star_Rarity = 6}
    }
}
```